# How to restrict the user from entering space at the beginning in a textfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
inputFormatters: [
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^[^\s][a-zA-Z ]')),
              ],
```

I tried this regex expression in the TextFormField but it is not taking alphabets also. I want the text field to restrict the space at the beginning but allow in the middle.
How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `TextEditingController`:

```
final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
```

---

```
TextFormField(
  controller: controller,
),
```

---

```
controller.text.trimLeft()
```

Answer (score 1):

just use function
`trimLeft()`
with your TextEditingController Like this

```
yourController.text.trimLeft()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the controller like MyCar said and additionaly put a logic in the onChanged() method of the text field. Then just check if the first character is space and if yes, remove it.

```
TextFormField(
  controller: controller,
  onChanged: (value) {
    if (value.isNotEmpty) {
      if (value[0] == " ") {
        controller.text = value.trimLeft();
      }
    }
  },
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class CustomFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  CustomFormatter();

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (newValue.text.isNotEmpty) {
      if (newValue.text.length > oldValue.text.length) {
        return TextEditingValue(text: newValue.text.trimLeft(), selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newValue.text.trim().isNotEmpty ? newValue.selection.end : 0));
      } else {
        return newValue;
      }
    }
    return newValue;
  }
}


TextField(
     inputFormatters: [CustomFormatter()],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex only allows one symbol in range of `[a-zA-Z]`. To allow multiple symbols you should try this:

```
RegExp(r'^[^\s][a-zA-Z ]*$')
```

or shorter:

```
RegExp(r'^\S[a-zA-Z ]*$')
```